# Self-regressing python version with Conda and Pycharm when installing PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-imaging-library, conda

I generated a conda environment (named `setest` here as an example) from pycharm in python 3.6.

I check via command line if it's the correct version, like so :

```
~/anaconda3/envs $ setest/bin/python
Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  9 2018, 12:34:16) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So far, so good.

I install a PIL from Pycharm (option Alt + Enter on a failed dependency -> Install package *package_name*, PIL in this situation).

I go back in the terminal to check my python version.

```
~/anaconda3/envs $ setest/bin/python
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 10 2018, 21:32:13) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
~/anaconda3/envs $ source activate setest
(setest) ~/anaconda3/envs $ python
Python 2.7.15 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 10 2018, 21:32:13) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Ta-da ! My whole python interpreter has regressed from 3.6 to 2.7. Funny thing is that Pycharm still display `Python 3.6.6` in the IDE (interpreter menu), although its clearly python 2.7 (even the code-coloration changes).

Question : **How can I stop this weird regressing behaviour while still installing my needed packages ?**

How can I ensure my python version will not regress again in the future installing another package ? Preferably still with the convenience of Pycharm IDE.

Comment: Don't use PIL, use Pillow, the newer fork of PIL. You'll have to install it from the command line, not PyCharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved my problem.

As darthbith suggested, I simply did not use the IDE to install PIL/Pillow, but instead I've run the command (after deleting and re-creating a new env in python 3) :

```
(setest) $ conda install pillow
```

Which settled my problem. Pillow got installed without changing my python version. I guess now I'll try to keep an eye on python version after installing any package...

However I would've liked an answer which used the IDE, or have some kind of more convenient solution to prevent it from happening again.